# Sorting a Dynamic 2D Array according to a column in JAVA

Tags: java

I have created an ArrayList of arrays which may contain n rows but two fixed columns. For e.g.

```
ArrayList<int[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add(new int[] {3, 100});
rows.add(new int[] {4, 150});
rows.add(new int[] {4, 80});
rows.add(new int[] {2, 90});
rows.add(new int[] {2, 300});
```

Note that there may be more rows. I want to sort these list of rows based on the second column. How do I go about doing that? If there is any other better method to do this not based on ArrayList, please let me know that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Comparator::comparingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)

Use it as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<int[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add(new int[] { 3, 100 });
        rows.add(new int[] { 4, 150 });
        rows.add(new int[] { 4, 80 });
        rows.add(new int[] { 2, 90 });
        rows.add(new int[] { 2, 300 });

        // Sort arrays (i.e. rows) on the value at index, 1 (i.e. second column)
        rows.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e[1]));

        // Display
        rows.forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 80]
[2, 90]
[3, 100]
[4, 150]
[2, 300]
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use comparator of collections class also..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<int[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add(new int[] {3, 100});
        rows.add(new int[] {4, 150});
        rows.add(new int[] {4, 80});
        rows.add(new int[] {2, 90});
        rows.add(new int[] {2, 300});
        Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<int[]>() {    

            @Override
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (o1[1] > o2[1]) 
                    return 1; 
                else
                    return -1;
            }     

    });
        rows.forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
    }
```

Comment: This is a pretty old way of using `Comparator`. Java-8 introduced a lot of convenient methods in [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and you should learn using them.